# Check, if all classes in project have a specific annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, project

My current situation: I want to write a test that checks, if all my files with "Service" in the name have the "@Valid" Annotation. I tried researching it but could not find anything.

Comment: Related: [Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) can be used to check the annotations of a class.

E.g. the following code prints the name and value of each class annotation of type `MyAnnotation`.

```
Class aClass = TheClass.class;
Annotation[] annotations = aClass.getAnnotations();

for(Annotation annotation : annotations){
    if(annotation instanceof MyAnnotation){
        MyAnnotation myAnnotation = (MyAnnotation) annotation;
        System.out.println("name: " + myAnnotation.name());
        System.out.println("value: " + myAnnotation.value());
    }
}
```

[source](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html)

The comment by Lino shows how to find all classes in the current classpath.